# to save very basic column values to my order table via hibernate

Tags: hibernate, object

I am trying to save very basic column values to my order table via hibernate. The columns are Customer no,[enter image description here][1] an integer type.I have created my order class and included the annotations. not sure where is the syntax error in my SQL. Please help.

the main class file looks good.
The DB connection is successful!
not sure when I try to save the object, it throws a SQL syntax error.

thanks! Please find my POJO and relevant mappings/annotations.

this is my Order Class: import javax.persistence.Column;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER")
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Order_no")
    private int _OrderNo;



    @Column(name="Customer_no")
    private int _CustomerNo;

    public Order() {

    }

    public Order(int CustomerNo) {


        this._CustomerNo = CustomerNo;
    }



    public int get_OrderNo() {
        return _OrderNo;
    }

    public void set_OrderNo(int OrderNo) {
        this._OrderNo = OrderNo;
    }


    public int get_CustomerNo() {
        return _CustomerNo;
    }

    public void set_CustomerNo(int CustomerNo) {
        this._CustomerNo = CustomerNo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Order [_OrderNo=" + _OrderNo + ",  _CustomerNo=" + _CustomerNo + "]";
    }

}
```

---

this is my actual object saving file.

```
public class CreateOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Order.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();



        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {



            System.out.println("Creating the Order Object.......");

            Order tempOrder = new Order(123);


            session.beginTransaction();


            System.out.println("Saving the Order ");
            session.save(tempOrder);


            session.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("Done!!");
        }

        finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_retail?useSSL=false</property>
        <property name="connection.username">hbstudent</property>
        <property name="connection.password">hbstudent</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Set the current session context -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

---

pls find here the stacktrace

```
:Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2909)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:280)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:676)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.mrunalini.demoApril20.hibernateEntities.CreateOrder.main(CreateOrder.java:34)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER (Customer_no) values (123)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3976)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3912)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Hibernate generates a query that fails. Probably you POJO to table mapping is messed up.

Comment: 1) Dont paste image of code but actual code. 2)Dont patte image of stacktrace but actual stacktrace

Comment: 3) Paste hibernate.cfg 4) dont put code in comments but edit your question 5) There is nothing in "here")

Comment: And where is stacktrace ?

Comment: @ventsyv My mapping of the Class to the DB table as you can see, looks good.any thoughts?

Comment: post your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your Table nam `@Table(name="ORDER")`

`ORDER` is reserved keyword in MySQL (you probably heard about `ORDER BY`?) thus it cannot be used directly as table name in in `INSERT`. The simplest way will be to change table name to somethig else, eg `ORDERS`

One workaround is to include quotemarks in table name like this

```
@Table(name="`ORDER`")
```

or for JPA2

```
@Table(name="\"ORDER\"")
```

but those may break RDMBS compatibility. IMHO tables should be named in plural form.